# Add/Set product Images and gallery images programmatically

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm getting data from jSON file and trying to setup the images for a product, My goal is -
need to develop a way to extract/download images from JSON responses and set images to related product
//$product_data is getting the response from Json

```
$product_data = $_REQUEST['data'];
$product = new WC_Product_Simple();
$product->set_name( $product_data['Title'] ); // it's working
$product->set_status( 'publish' );
$product->save();
```

If it has multiple images that need to be assigned to a product, the first image need to assign as the featured image/thumbnail, and then assign the rest of the images as the product gallery thumbnails.

Comment: $product->set_image_id($image_id);  $product->set_gallery_image_ids($gallery_image_ids);

Comment: I don't have any image ID, i have only image path, to get ID we need to first download/get image in media so we can get ID and then set it as a featured.

Comment: $upload = wc_rest_upload_image_from_url($url); 
$id = wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment($upload, $product_id);

Comment: If it has multiple images that need to be assigned to a product, the first image need to assign as the featured image/thumbnail, and then assign the rest of the images as the product gallery thumbnails.

--- Do you have any solution for this one? @mujuonly

Comment: $product->set_gallery_image_ids($gallery_image_ids);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$product_images = [];
            $count = 0;
            foreach($product_data as $product_key => $product_value):
                if (strpos($product_key, 'Image') !== false):

                    $product_img_upload = wc_rest_upload_image_from_url(esc_url_raw($product_value));
                    $product_img_id = wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment($product_img_upload, $product_data);

                    // Add image ID to array.
                    $product_images[] = $product_img_id;

                    $count++;

                endif;
            endforeach;

            if (!empty( $product_images ) ) {
                $product->set_image_id( $product_images[0] );
                array_shift($product_images);
                $product->set_gallery_image_ids( $product_images);
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: $product_img_id = wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment($product_img_upload, $product_data);
on this line there should be product id instead of $product_data. Anyone knows how to get product id before $product->save(); OR use this function wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment after the  $product->save();  ?